# Two Listviews on a single aspx page

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have 2 asp.net Listviews on a aps.net page, lv1 and lv2.  I ma having a hard time trying to access lv1's data items from lv2's.  I needed to do it make comparisons for the items in both the listviews  and color code unequal items.

Is it possible to access one listview's data items from another one on the same page?

Below is the code:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ListView ID="lst1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table class="tblClass" width="95%" border="0" style="margin: auto; font-size: 13px;
                    height: 150px;">
                    <br />
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Account#:
                        </td>
                        <td align="right">
                            <b>
                                <%#Eval("ID")%></b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Email:
                        </td>
                        <td  align="right">
                            <%#Eval("DefaultEmail")%>
                            <input type="radio" id="rad1" <%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DefaultEmail").ToString()) ? "disabled" : " ")%>
                                name="radEmail" value="<%#Eval("DefaultEmail") %>" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:ListView ID="lst2" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table class="tblClass" width="95%" border="0" style="margin: auto; font-size: 13px;
                    height: 150px;">
                    <br />
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Account#:
                        </td>
                        <td align="right">
                            <b>
                                <%#Eval("ID")%></b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Email:
                        </td>
                        <td  align="right">
                            <%#Eval("DefaultEmail")%>
                            <input type="radio" id="rad2" <%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DefaultEmail").ToString()) ? "disabled" : " ")%>
                                name="radEmail" value="<%#Eval("DefaultEmail") %>" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to access lst2's Email item within the lst1 using maybe an EVAL...This way I can color code the tr elements if the two values are different.

Comment: It might help if you posted how you're currently trying to do this.

Comment: @user1967701 Where are the datasources?

Comment: Doing a Databind from code behind on page_load

Answer (score 1):

How about solving this inside your collections before binding them to listiviews?

Something like this:

- Add additional property on your class (one that you bind to listview1) for example: `bool EmailExists`
- Iterate through collection, that gets binds to listview1, and search for emails in second collection (that gets bind to listView2). If you find a match set EmailExists property to True.
- Use `<%#Eval(EmailExists) %>` to appropriately color tr elements based of value of EmailExists

Comment: THanks Uros.  Here's where I am having a problem: ListView1 has a databind (Select ID, Email from TableA where ID=1) and Listview2 has a databind (Select ID, Email from TableA where ID=2). Can I still do what you were suggesting?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, i think you can. I suppose you fill your query results into a list of objects before you bind data to lostviews.

Comment: THanks.  I was able to use one list view and re-wrote the query to get the two rows into a single row.